# SQL query/Spark dataframe to outer join and subtract values of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking to do an outer join on two tables A and B based on 'name', and then subtract the column 'count' values, substituting 0 if the row doesn't exist in the other table. Does anyone know a simple SQL query to make this possible?

```
A
name count
ABC 10
DEF 10
GHI 20

B
name count
ABC 20
GHI 30
XYZ 10

RESULT
name count
ABC -10
DEF 10
GHI -10
XYZ -10
```

Thanks!

(or if there is a way to do this with Spark DataFrames that would be great as well!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `spark`, you can join the two data frames on `name` column, `coalesce` `null` count to zero and then subtract `A.count` with `B.count`:

```
(A.alias("a").join(B.alias("b"), Seq("name"), "outer")
  .selectExpr("name", "coalesce(a.count, 0) - coalesce(b.count, 0) as count")).show
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
| DEF|   10|
| GHI|  -10|
| XYZ|  -10|
| ABC|  -10|
+----+-----+
```